# How can add record into an xml file from the page in React

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to add record from the react page into an xml file.I have two component file js file Register and UserStorage. If I call onSumbit() method in Register , the changed value is passing as props from register page into UserStorage.registerUser. I am trying to write the code insert the record into xml from UserStorage.registerUser.Here is my code

Src\Data\User.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="users">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="user" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:complexType> 
        <xs:attribute name="Email" type="xs:string"/>           
            <xs:attribute name="Password" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:attribute name="FirstName" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:attribute name="LastName" type="xs:string"/>              
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

In Register page

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Userstorage from "../Storage/Userstorage";

const initialState = {
  firstName: "",
  lastName: "",
  mobile: "",
  email: "",
  password: "",
  role: "",
  isMember: true,
};

const Register = () => {
  const [values, setValues] = useState(initialState);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const name = e.target.name;
    const value = e.target.value;    
    setValues({ ...values, [name]: value });
  };

  const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { firstName, lastName, email, password, isMember } = values;         
    Userstorage.registerUser(values); // Value passing into Userstorage RegisterUser method
  };
```

UserStorage

```
const registerUser = (values) => {
  console.log(values);
  // Here, to write the record into xml file. Value is passed from Register page
};

const loginuser = () => {
  console.log("users");
};

const Userstorage = {
  registerUser,
  loginuser,
};

export default Userstorage;
```

Answer (score 1):

To add a record to an XML file from a page in React, you can follow these general steps:

Import the XML file into your React application as a data source.

Create a form component in React that allows the user to input the data that needs to be added to the XML file.

When the form is submitted, capture the form data and create a new record object.

Use an XML parser library (such as xml2js or xml-js) to convert the XML data into a JavaScript object.

Add the new record object to the JavaScript object that represents the XML data.

Convert the updated JavaScript object back into XML format using the XML parser library.

Save the updated XML data to the XML file using a server-side script or an API endpoint.

Here is an example code snippet that demonstrates the basic idea:

```js
import { useState } from 'react';
import { parseString } from 'xml2js';

function AddRecordForm() {
  const [recordData, setRecordData] = useState({
    // Initialize form data state here
  });

  const handleFormSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    enter code here

    // Create new record object from form data here

    const response = await fetch('/update-xml', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify({ newRecord }),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    });

    // Handle response here
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleFormSubmit}>
      {/* Render form inputs here */}
    </form>
  );
}
```

In this example, parseString is a function provided by the xml2js library that can convert an XML string into a JavaScript object. The fetch function is used to make a POST request to a server-side endpoint that handles updating the XML file. The response from the server can be handled using the then method on the fetch promise.